# Selecting listbox item updates another listbox

Tags: ms-access

Consider the following relationships:

[image]

Here's a form which contains a list box for the nodes and a list box for the labels:

[image]

When I select a label, I'd like for the nodes list box to only show nodes which are associated with that label.

What's a good way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the BeforeUpdate Event of the Labels List insert something like this:

```
Me.NodeList.RowSource="SELECT * FROM Nodes INNER JOIN Nodes_Labels ON Nodes.ID = Nodes_Labels.Node WHERE (Nodes_Labels.Label = " & Me.LabelList.value & ");"
Me.NodeList.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the event handler I used (based on Johanness' answer):

```
Private Sub LabelsListBox_Click()

    NodesListBox.RowSource = _
        "SELECT Nodes.ID, Nodes.Title " & _
        "FROM Nodes INNER JOIN Nodes_Labels ON Nodes.ID = Nodes_Labels.Node " & _
        "WHERE Nodes_Labels.Label = " & LabelsListBox.Value & " ORDER BY Title;"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Johaness' answer involves updating the `NodesListBox.RowSource` each time the `NodesListBox` `BeforeUpdate` event is triggered.

Another approach is to give `NodesListBox` a static `RowSource` which references `LabelsListBox`.

This approach is shown in the following query editor screenshot:

[image]

Then, the `LabelsListBox` event handler is simply:

```
Private Sub LabelsListBox_Click()
    NodesListBox.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Click is probably the better event for this. You would also have to make sure that the code is executed after you chaged to another dataset. I don't think it makes a big difference from the performance prespective, if you use this approach or mine. I myself try to keep as much as possible in Code as soon as i start to use VBA. Its easier to spot where data is changed when you come back to the project later.